# Importing HTML/CSS project into a visual front-end editor

Tags: javascript, html, css, divshot

is that possible to import my project (HTML/CSS/JS) into any bootstrap editor and edit it from there?

I'm looking for a way that I can modify my existing web project using a visual editor (WYSIWYG).

Comment: Are you looking for an installable application or a web-based application?

Comment: Hi djthoms, I'm looking for a web-based application such as Divshot. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. Several Bootstrap WYSIWYG editors will allow you to copy over your existing HTML/CSS/JS. With Divshot you can import your entire project at once and have all of your files appear in a file tree as you might expect with any desktop based text editor or IDE. Just click the `+` icon in the navigator panel and select `Upload Files`. From there you can move, duplicate, delete or rename your files and manage them however you'd like!

Comment: Got it, Jake. What if my application is on dust.js? My problem is that I can test locally without problems, but I'm afraid that using an online editor I won't be able to upload and test properly my entire main page.

Comment: It looks like Dust.js can compile templates in the browser if you add a script tag to the page: <script src="dust-full-0.3.0.min.js"></script>. If you're building a Node.js and MongoDB application with the front-end and back-end closely knit together and you want to use an online editor like Divshot, you'd probably have to keep the UI separate for now and integrate later. So you could use Dust.js in Divshot with HTML/CSS/JS, then when you're done export to a ZIP file and integrate into your Node application.

Comment: Divshot can handle JavaScript frameworks with templating like AngularJS as well. For now we play well with back-end as a service providers such as Firebase and Parse. In the future we may consider Node.js support. We're advocates of separating the front-end and back-end into two distinct applications -- a front-end with static HTML/CSS/JS communicating with a back-end REST API via AJAX (and CORS). If you have any additional questions feel free to reach out at support@divshot.com!

Comment: Great, thanks Jake. Yes, I'm using node.js and MongoDB for building the application, I need to find a way to keep the UI separate and integrate later, as you said.

Comment: After I make the front-end static, I'll definitely be using Divshot. Now let me figure out how to make it static! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't exactly what you're asking, but have you tried Firefox and exporting all the css afterwards?

Comment: Hi Kelly, that's an alternative. However, I have multiple .css and .js files, which make it difficult to export each one.